# Can you check how many times a function is called without getMock in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

My test suite calls `accepted` in Object A. That function will then call `insert` for Object B a certain number of times, depending on which test I'm running.

I want to verify that `insert` is being called the right amount of times in each test. I don't *think* I can count it using mock since Object A wouldn't be hitting the mock within my test.

I saw this question from 2 years ago:
[PHPUnit Test How Many Times A Function Is Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809260/phpunit-test-how-many-times-a-function-is-called)

Using a global variable for counting isn't ideal since I shouldn't have code in my class that is specifically for a class.

**EDIT**

It would probably be helpful to note that `insert` is static. Even if I mock the class and specify I only want to mock that function, it still calls `new` on the mocked object which is another roadblock I'm facing.

**ANSWER**
The answer is no. I just want @zerkms to give that answer since he was the one helping me so I can accept it.

I ended up figuring I can use just one object but did hit another roadblock:
[Why isn't PHPUnit counting this function as having ran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537100/why-isnt-phpunit-counting-this-function-as-having-ran)

Comment: So now you understand why static is evil :-)

Comment: I just saw some hating on static methods while research this. Is the correct thing to make an empty object and then call instance method on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like in this particular case it is impossible.

But in some specific cases you can mock static methods: http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html

```
class Foo
{
    public static function doSomething()
    {
        return static::helper();
    }

    public static function helper()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
```

test:

```
public function testQQQ()
{
    $class = $this->getMockClass(
        'Foo',          /* name of class to mock     */
        array('helper') /* list of methods to mock   */
    );

    $class::staticExpects($this->exactly(2))
        ->method('helper')
        ->will($this->returnValue('bar'));

    $this->assertEquals(
        'bar',
        $class::doSomething()
    );
}
```

Result:

```
$ phpunit --filter QQQ
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/.../phpunit.xml

F

Time: 1 second, Memory: 10.75Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) ...::testQQQ
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:helper> when invoked 2 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 2 times, actually called 1 times.


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: That's the article I was just reading that was bashing static :) When I mock the static function, it's still calling new on my object. Also even if I mock the static function I don't think my other object would have access to that. My other object wouldn't have a reference to `$class`

Comment: @Dave Stein: I'm not sure I understand the situation. You said that you need to count of calls of a static method. Here it is

Comment: "My other object wouldn't have a reference to $class" --- and it shouldn't have. You set up a mock in test method

Comment: I'm not good at explaining things so thanks for baring with me. My test is for Object B. I call a method in Object A which calls static method in Object B. The static method is just populating a table based on information from Object A. So my test is calling Object A's method, which calls B. I then verify that the last row for B is correct. I want to also verify that the method was only called once.

Comment: @Dave Stein: so the example above looks similar to what you just explained

Comment: The example is only using one class. If I use a mock like that, does it still run the internals of the original function but I can change the output on top of that?

Comment: @Dave Stein: oh, now I see. Yep, you are right, in that case you cannot do that (so static are still evil ;-)

Comment: you might as well leave an answer saying "No" to my question so I can mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Excellent. Maybe you know the answer to my next mind-bender http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541683/how-can-i-use-php-reflection-to-set-a-static-property

Answer (score 0):

You could use [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) to redefine the static method on the fly (you probably shouldn't, though). Other than that, you will have to restructure the code. Either use non-static calls and dependency injection (so object A receives object B from an external source, and your test can pass a mock instead) or use a dependency injection container so that the class name is not wired in and your test can create a mock subclass and make class A use it (this is more messy, but needs much less change in your non-test code as you can leave your methods static).

Comment: I heard of runkit in a few posts and it seemed like the thing not to use ( even youre saying not to use it at same time ). I was able to restructure code but am still running into some hurdles that I am asking about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541683/how-can-i-use-php-reflection-to-set-a-static-property