# Why isn't PHPUnit counting this function as having ran?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have code like this inside my unit test:

```
// $item_id was defined above
$originalMock = $this->getMock( 'Item', array( 'foo' ), array(
  $item_id
));

$originalMock->expects( $this->once() )->method( 'foo' );

$originalMock->functionThatCallsFoo();
```

It is saying I'm not calling `foo` at all, even though `functionThatCallsFoo` & `foo` are var_dumping out from within.

There are several function calls between the publicly called function and the one I'm expecting. I made sure there are no static functions called down the chain. ( There were originally but I changed them to see if I can get this working at all )

**EDIT**
I changed my `expects` call to match the method directly called from `functionThatCallsFoo` and it still did not work.

Comment: You're not specifying a list of mocked methods in `getMock()`. The second param should be `array('foo')` not `null`

Comment: @MikeB "When the second (optional) parameter is provided, only the methods whose names are in the array are replaced with a configurable test double. The behavior of the other methods is not changed." http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html I wanted to mock the entire class since there are several intermediary functions

Comment: Yes.. and your intent is to change the behavior of `foo()` right? You won't be able to count the invocations of the concrete `foo()` method in your class, only mocked/stubbed methods.

Comment: @MikeB  I wanted to mock the entire class since there are several intermediary functions. I actually tried specifying foo before and it didn't work. Trying it again now, after switching some behavior of the class worked. I'll just go backwards until it breaks again to see what I'm doing wrong in my code. I'm betting it was static function issue

Comment: @MikeB I posted my answer. You were right about not using `null` Specifying `foo` wasn't working earlier for the reasons I listed. I still wonder why `null` wouldn't work there since it's supposed to mock everything at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this question since I had a world of problems with my code. Hopefully this answer will be a bit of a checklist if someone else has similar problems in the future.

1. My final method was static so I needed to use staticExpects instead of expects
2. My static calls were using self:: but I needed to use static:: ( PHP >= 5.3 )
3. static:: can't be used on a private function, unlike self::

In the end, I can now see why static functions are evil.