# How can I use PHP reflection to set a static property?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am using PHPUnit to make a mock class for testing.

```
class Item extends Object {
  protected static $_cache;
}
```

I am pretty certain mocking does something like this ( please correct me if I'm wrong ):

```
class Mock_Item_randomstring extends Item {

}
```

When my `Item`'s cache gets populated, it's checking to see that the object being passed in is an instance of `Item`. Since the mock is not explicitly defining `$_cache`, it fails the check for instance type.

PHP doesn't really document the reflection functions well at all. Is there a way to set the static variable after the fact so the class would become

```
class Mock_Item_randomstring extends Item {
  protected static $_cache;
}
```

**EDIT**

I played around with reflection methods and ran into a variety of issues. Here is one that I'm confused about:

```
$mock = $this->getMock( 'Item', array( '_func' ), array(
  $argument1, $argument2
));

$mock = new ReflectionClass($mock); 


$mock->staticExpects( $this->exactly(2) )->method( '_func' );
```

I was under the assumption reflections copy the entire class. I get this error:
`Call to undefined method ReflectionClass::staticExpects()`

Comment: Don't know about this one, but you definitely need to avoid such cases using any of dependency injection techniques.

Comment: I would avoid this entirely if looking at static::$_cache didn't go to Item since it's not explicitly defined in the mock. Damn limitations of PHP + static things. We don't use manager objects hence the cache and static methods.

Comment: Using static variables *will* get you into trouble (what you are doing here is basically a singleton, and you can read a lot about why that is evil), but I don't see why it would cause you to fail a type check. Can you post the code? (Also, not sure what you want to achieve by defining the same variable in a child class, but it would still share it's value with the parent.)

Comment: @Tgr When things are put into the cache, it checks that the incoming object is matching the class that gets the object. `Mock` doesn't have the property so it inserts into the `Item` cache, rather than the `Mock` cache. `Item` throws an exception saying it has gotten `Mock`

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a somewhat nasty trick for per-class static variables in subclasses:

```
class A {
    protected static $cache;
    public static function getCache() {
        return static::$cache;
    }
    public static function setCache($val) {
        static::$cache = & $val; // note the '&'
    }
}
class B extends A {}

A::setCache('A');
B::setCache('B');
A::getCache(); // 'A'
B::getCache(); // 'B'
```

Of course, it is the best to avoid static variables in the first place. Use a dedicated cache object and inject it when the class is instantiated.

Comment: To answer your orginal question, reflection does not allow you to define classes (you can just use eval though, [which is what PHPUnit does](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/master/PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php#L233)), much less to change an already defined class (you need runkit for that, and things might break). Setting a non-public static property of an already existing class with reflection is possible, but nasty again - see [the comments for setStaticPropertyValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.setstaticpropertyvalue.php).

Comment: what comments? :) "There are no user contributed notes for this page." Would using that actually set it as though it were inside `Mock`? Or would it be setting it as if it were inside `Item`?

Comment: My bad - I meant the comments for [getStaticPropertyValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getstaticpropertyvalue.php), but I tested it in the meanwhile and it does not work. Using `getProperty`/`setAccessible`/`setValue` works in 5.3, but I wouldn't bet on it not breaking in the future (for example, the same method does not work for reading the value).

Comment: If you create the reflection object from the mock classname, it works as if you were inside that class. It should not matter for you, though  - since the property is only defined in the parent class, the children share it with the parent, so setting the value on `Item` or `Mock` with reflection has the same effect. (Well, more precisely, the property of the child is a reference to the property of the parent. That is why the trick described in my answer works. You cannot do the same through a function call, though.)

Comment: I've been trying to do this all day but have been swamped. Looks like I'll be able to tackle it Monday. I'll keep you posted. Thanks for the thorough responses in meantime.

Comment: If use phpunit to mock `Item`and then do a reflection on the mock, it tells me the reflection doesn't have the method `staticExpects` - isn't it supposed to copy all methods? I'm going to put code above

Comment: A reflection is not a copy, it is an alternative access point to the original object, through which you can do things you could not do normally (such as changing protected variables). None of the methods and properties are copied to the reflection object.

Comment: That clears things up. I think I can try making the mock, making a reflection change, and then running the constructor. I don't know if that's possible though. I think when I tried the other day I couldn't set a property that way I wanted...

Comment: In theory, that should work. Although I do not see the point of changing stuff before the constructor runs if your problem is with static properties... you can just change those before you instantiate the object. And anyway, you can override `__construct` in your mock and do stuff before invoking the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to. `\Closure::bind` lets you read and assign private and protected static properties. See the example code on http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php

Comment: I won't be on 5.4 for a while. It's funny it doesn't mention it's 5.4 only on the bind page, just the Closure: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

Comment: If 5.4+ solves your problem, and the only other solution is to redesign your classes, why not push to get on 5.4 sooner?

Comment: Because there would most likely be a lot of extension compatibility issues across many sites and servers we have